# Is it possible to query in mongodb with field appended with randomid

Tags: mongodb

I have a field `priority` which is appended with randomid generated ex":

```
"priority_123":"HIGH" ,"priority_234"..."HIGH"
```

I want query the value of priority field somehow using regex on field like 
`{"priority_":"HIGH"}`

Is it possible or do i need to change my structure of saving the field?

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

One (and perhaps the only) way I think this could be achieved, is by using the [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator.

```
db.collection.find({
    $where: function() {
        for (var key in this) {
            if (key.indexOf('priority_') === 0 && this[key] === 'HIGH') {
                 return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }
})
```

Although, as you can tell, it's much slower than a regular query, since it makes the database execute JavaScript for each document. I'd not recommend using this, especially if there can be a large amount of documents in your collection.

A better approach would be to change your structure, as you have already mentioned.
Maybe something like this?

```
[{
    priority: {
        salt: '123',
        value: 'HIGH',
    }
}, {
    priority: {
        salt: '234',
        value: 'HIGH',
    }
}]

db.collection.find({
    'priority.value': 'HIGH'
})
```